# Download image with Kingfisher from Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, kingfisher

Inside my app I store images in **Firebase Storage**  and also its `url` to **Cloud Firestore**.
Now when I try to retrieve this image I am using **Kingfisher** but I think I have a misunderstanding of how **Kingfisher** works. This is my code:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage()
    if let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) {
        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: imageUrl)
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                print("success")
            case .failure(_):
                print("fail")
            }
        }
    }
dataSourceArrayWithWishes[wishIDX].wishes.append(image: imageView.image!)
```

What I would like to to here is if the `imageUrl` is correct, retrieve it and then save it to `dataSourceArrayWithWishes` as a `UIImage`. If not, then just save an empty `UIImage`.

However when a valid `imageUrl` is given, it fails because `imageView.image!` must not be null.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it here inside success block

```
        case .success(_):
            print("success") 
           dataSourceArrayWithWishes[wishIDX].wishes.append(image: imageView.image!)
        case .failure(_):
            print("fail")
        }
    }
}
```

This  `imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource) { (result) in` is an asynchnous method meaning that the line being crashed `dataSourceArrayWithWishes[wishIDX].wishes.append(image: imageView.image!)` runs before the image is fetched from firebase hence it's nil

Comment: alright that makes sense, thanks for the explained answer!